# Facebook API - posting to a timeline

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

I know this can't be that difficult; maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Hopefully you can help me.

I have a website that needs to be able to post a string to someone's Facebook timeline.

I've gotten them to login properly, but I haven't found any working code to submit information to their timeline after they've given permission.

I've followed the example [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/) with no luck. I've

- Created an App
- Logged into Facebook
- Defined a Cook action with a recipe object
- Created a page on my website with the code that they provided, replacing `[your_app_id]` with my app id
- Attempted to post a cook action

But when I click the cook button on their sample page on my site, it gives me the error:

```
No callback passed to the ApiClient for https://graph.facebook.com/me/fblaevents:cook
```

and the `error occurred` browser alert pops up.

Here is the sample code that I'm using:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fblaevents: 
              http://ogp.me/ns/apps/fblaevents#">
  <title>OG Tutorial App</title>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="542182755801091" /> 
  <meta property="og:type" content="fblaevents:recipe" /> 
  <meta property="og:title" content="Stuffed Cookies" /> 
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.jpg" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="The Turducken of Cookies" /> 
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function postCook()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/fblaevents:cook',
        'post',
        { recipe: 'http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html' },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
       });
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '542182755801091', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
  </script>

  <h3>Stuffed Cookies</h3>
  <p>
    <img title="Stuffed Cookies" 
         src="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.jpg" 
         width="550"/>
  </p>

  <br>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Cook" onclick="postCook()" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If there is an easier way, please point it out to me. I don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the OG meta tags and the recipe url in your JS code with your own. As the above code is a starting code only, not a working demo (or maybe it was but now the links are dead).

Also since you are getting `Error occured` then most probably `response.error` has something in it, so you should check its value by calling the console method for example:

```
if (!response || response.error) {
   console.log('Error occured: ', response.error);
} else {
```

This would give you:

> Error occured:  Object {type: "Exception", message: "Could not
>   retrieve data from URL.", code: 1660002}